# How to open a .pdf file from QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Is there any way to open a .pdf file from QML or I have to do it in C++ via **QDesktopServices** , and if I used QDesktopServices would it work without any problem in **Android**.

Thanks.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It is Qt 5.2.1 for Android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to open a .pdf file from QML or I have to do it in C++ via QDesktopServices

The only thing I am aware of is the following:

```
Qt.openUrlExternally("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001582/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-from-qml/23002658");
```

Based on the comments, it seems to work on Android

In your particular case, it would become:

```
Qt.openUrlExternally("path/to/my/foo.pdf");
```

> and if I used QDesktopServices would it work without any problem in Android

The question lacks a question mark, but nitpicking aside, this oughta work. This bug was also fixed in Qt 5.2.0. That is why I asked about the version, but other than this, I am not aware of any other critical issues:

[QDesktopServices::openUrl crashes Application](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34600)

Comment: Qt.openUrlExternally Worked for pdf in the local system, I didn't test it with android yet. 

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Baso: OK, let me know, and I will update my reply if it works on Android.

Comment: ! Qt.openUrlExternally Did work in Android like it should be.

Comment: Why one downvote here? May I ask for the reason? Usually, I do not mind it, but considering that I got lots of them the last 2-3 days, I began to think about deleting my account - but at least leaving SO for a while -, because this is more than unfair to get 15-20 of them without any explanation.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp if it's exactly 1 downvote on a contiguous set of comments, it's likely someone who was displeased by one of your edit or answer, and who is downvoting you. A poor attitude, but seen on websites with an upvote/downvote system like reddit. Better to ignore a bad apple, and continue as a support for the community.

Comment: @Armaghast: I appreciate your willingness to cheer me up. I will propose a change in the system on meta soon, which I think mostly can fix this issue.

Comment: Note that I'm unsure if this is actually the case; About mass downvoters: the "downvoting removes a point to both of you" is a very good system. Also, I believe reddit use anti-"cheat" systems like detecting when a user use the profile page to find and downvote comments/answer of someone, which may be done here too. However, if it's not the same person who is downvoting: maybe it's just bad luck, you are still gaining a lot of positive feedback, that's the more important.

Comment: How do you use this to load a local .pdf in Android? I've tried both "data/data/com.velneo.vclient.v7/files/TEST_BB.pdf" and "file:///data/data/com.velneo.vclient.v7/files/TEST_BB.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from QML using the V-Play FileUtils: https://v-play.net/doc/fileutils/

```
fileUtils.openFile("<path to pdf file>")
```

Here is an example code that downloads a PDF from the web and opens it using the default application on Android and iOS: https://v-play.net/web-editor/?snippet=ce64a995